# How can I make a windows 8 recovery drive - CD - using Linux Fedora?

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, fedora

My HP 250G3 Windows 8(.1?) computer one day didn't boot - "Boot Device Not Found (...)"
**The hard disk drive tests passed.**
When I press F11 during startup, nothing happens. Now I have only a old Linux Fedora computer (with [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)).

**Can I make a windows 8 recovery drive out of a 700MB CD on a Linux Fedora computer?** If a CD is too small, I'll use my flash disk. If anybody gave me a for-dummies tour, it would be the best.

***Why does evrybody downvote?** Can't I ask a question after doing lots of work on this without any success?!?!*

Comment: Just boot to a Windows 8 installation disk, has everything you need, much easier

Comment: @Ramhound what? I don't speak Computer, sorry. ;-(

Comment: Recovery disk is called WinRE which exists on any Windows installation disk

Comment: How to access it when I can't start my computer?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is the "700MB CD" you speak of? Is it a bootable W8 installation disc? Or do you want to know how to create such a disc?

Comment: "Boot Device Not Found" more than likely the hard drive has failed and needs replaced, then use your HP recovery media to reinstall W8, if you do not have these recovery discs you can order then from HP....http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07143#AbT2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 won't fit on a CD. You'll have to use a flash drive probably. I had a similar problem, and ended up downloading a VM [from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/). From there, I used Parallels to run the VM and downloaded an ISO - you can get one [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) - then used Rufus (I can only put two links in this post, so that's something you'll have to Google yourself) to create a bootable flash drive.

Comment: could you place a link in the description? Many thanks.